# How to delay umount of SDcard on Android to complete my own file io

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My application needs a guaranteed time to complete some IO on an SDcard before the SDcard is unmounted. My solution is to write a linux kernel module that inserts a wrapper around the umount system call that will delay the actual umount and call me back to complete my work.

My code may have root privileged components.

Any less obstructive solutions?

Comment: It shouldn't let you unmount a drive that's currently being accessed. What are you doing that takes so long?

Comment: I am providing a special purpose filesystem (outside of Android, but with user privileges), and have some data buffered. I don't think just having some open file descriptors prevent the umount. That way any user application could block the system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't guarantee it, I believe that umount will automatically wait for that. That's one of the reasons to use umount (instead of directly removing the sdcard).

Also, you can't «write a linux kernel module» and "install" it into an android device. What you would have to do would involve recompiling android, making a custom ROM and install that to the desired device. Each device would need a different ROM, etc. I don't think this conceivable for you.

Anyway, umount should wait for any IO operation to finish (maybe with a timeout). I don't see a solution in case you have several files to send and what to ensure that all of them will be written.

Comment: Assume that my code gets installed by the OEMs into the r/o system filesystem, so yes, I can have a linux kernel module. Not that I want to. If possible I would like to avoid it. Your answer seems to suggest that you don't see any other way either. Correct? Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I didn't expect that to be a viable option... Anyway, I don't see another around it. But again: linux would say "Device is busy" and the umount would report an error. Maybe android does the same? See this linux example http://ocaoimh.ie/how-to-umount-when-the-device-is-busy/